# Horizontal List that wraps without overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a list (UL) which is displayed horizontally. Each item has some padding around it. The problem I'm having is that when the list gets to the end of the line and starts wrapping to the next line, it doesn't render low enough and starts overlapping the first line. Can someone help me figure out how to get the wrapping to go on to the next line without overlapping?

Here's the CSS

```
.letterlist ul {
   margin: 0; padding: 0; 
    list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none;
}

.letterlist li 
{
    display:inline;
}

.letterlist li a
{
    margin: 4px;
    color:#eee;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background:#3c66ad;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<p>
<ul class="letterlist">
    <li><a href="/list/A">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/B">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/C">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/D">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/E">E</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/F">F</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/G">G</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/H">H</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/I">I</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/J">J</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/K">K</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/L">L</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/M">M</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/N">N</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/O">O</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/P">P</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/Q">Q</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/R">R</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/S">S</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/T">T</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/U">U</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/V">V</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/W">W</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/X">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/Y">Y</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list/Z">Z</a></li>
</ul>
</p>
```

I'm using blueprint CSS if that matters.

Comment: When I put this into an editor and view it in Firefox, I don't see the problem.  What browser are you viewing it in?  (Also, I think you intend the first style to be for ul.letterlist - as .letterlist ul it looks for a ul element that's a child of something with the .letterlist class.)

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I see the same problem when I use firefox 3.6.8.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can either float all the `li` elements or give them `display: inline-block`, then give them some top and bottom margin:

```
.letterlist li {
    float: left; 
       /* or */ 
    display: inline-block;

    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/z8Gfe/ for a simple example. And by the way, `ul` elements are not valid in `p` paragraphs

Comment: The display: inline-block; rather than display: inline; fixed my issue with the list items overflowing the list boundaries.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Yi Jiang's answer can be simplified by using a flex box

```css
.letterlist {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 6px
}

.letterlist a {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color:#eee;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background:#3c66ad;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="letterlist">
    <a href="/list/A">A</a>
    <a href="/list/B">B</a>
    <a href="/list/C">C</a>
    <a href="/list/D">D</a>
    <a href="/list/E">E</a>
    <a href="/list/F">F</a>
    <a href="/list/G">G</a>
    <a href="/list/H">H</a>
    <a href="/list/I">I</a>
    <a href="/list/J">J</a>
    <a href="/list/K">K</a>
    <a href="/list/L">L</a>
    <a href="/list/M">M</a>
    <a href="/list/N">N</a>
    <a href="/list/O">O</a>
    <a href="/list/P">P</a>
    <a href="/list/Q">Q</a>
    <a href="/list/R">R</a>
    <a href="/list/S">S</a>
    <a href="/list/T">T</a>
    <a href="/list/U">U</a>
    <a href="/list/V">V</a>
    <a href="/list/W">W</a>
    <a href="/list/X">X</a>
    <a href="/list/Y">Y</a>
    <a href="/list/Z">Z</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked better for me with display: flex and flex-wrap: wrap; Seems a neater answer.